# Preventing selection on grid upon condition

Tags: vaadin

I've got a Vaadin `Grid` with a `SelectionListener`. When a particular (current) item is selected, its details are shown in a drawer (triggered by the `SelectionEvent`). The details can be edited, and when the user wants to navigate to another item in the `Grid` after having done particular changes in the detail drawer, a confirmation dialog pops up whether the user really wants to navigate away (again triggered by the `SelectionEvent`). If the user doesn't confirm (e.g. clicks on the "abort" button), the drawer of the current item remains open. However, in the `Grid`, the new item is shown as being selected. This new item needs to be deselected and selected again if the user wants to switch to its details later.

Is there a way to prevent selection of the new item within the `Grid` as long as the user hasn't pressed the "Confirm" button in the confirmation dialog?

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent the selection, but you can select the previous item manually in your `SelectionListener` if the user decides to cancel the switch of selection.